# Display a PDF file(Published google spreadsheet) in webview

Tags: android, pdf, google-sheets, webview

How to show a PDF (Published google spreadsheet) file in a webview?

I tried this :

```
String url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT7oTGfVsObkWBVo7WQvfZ0mqgeiafbs8i8IE8v1On_hW2NV8x9jWUXC6N7ZSlZ-TZFpC0O7Aj4cZY4/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=pdf";

mywebview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url);
```

but it's not working.